# URL field in EventReservation markup is not working as expected

Tags: schema.org, google-schemas

when i am trying to test email markup of event type EventReservation with a actionable CTA (clickable link) in calendar event, below is the markup code for the same in JSON-LD format

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EventReservation",
  "reservationNumber": "E123456789",
  "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
  "underName": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "John Smith"
  },
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type": "Event",
    "name": "Foo Fighters Concert",
    "startDate": "2020-03-04T15:06:00Z",
    "endDate": "2020-03-04T15:16:00Z",
    "location": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "name": "AT&T Park",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "24 Willie Mays Plaza",
        "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
        "addressRegion": "CA",
        "postalCode": "94107",
        "addressCountry": "US"
      }
    }
  },
  "url": "http://www.example.com"
}
</script>
```

the calendar event gets created while i am testing by sending an mail to myself thru app script but the problem is not seeing any clickable link in the calendar event which can take me to the url which mentioned above

[image of the calendar event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3y1L.png)

Google email markup documentation for eventReservation mentioned clearly to specify url in the markup. Ref - [eventReservation documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation#specification)

can anyone please help me with this or anything wrong in the markup ?

Comment: Maybe try `modifyReservationUrl` -or- `confirmReservationUrl` (Maybe google show button only for those properties). Your markup looks ok (You copy-paste the code from google docs). Try also to change URL value from `http` to `https`

Comment: tried with modifyReservationUrl not working tough, confirmReservationUrl is something different that cta appears when we hover on a mail item but in this case  i need the cta button to be on the calendar event, thanks